# remove div when option value unselected

Tags: javascript, laravel, html-select, ajaxform, laravelcollective

whats wrong with this?

```
            function admSelectCheck(nameSelect)
            {
                console.log(nameSelect);
                if(nameSelect){
                    admOptionValue = document.getElementById("admOption").value;
                    if(admOptionValue === nameSelect.value){
                        document.getElementById("admDivCheck").style.display = "block";
                    }
                    else{
                        document.getElementById("admDivCheck").style.display = "none";
                    }
                }
                else{
                    document.getElementById("admDivCheck").style.display = "none";
                }
            }
```

There is two options one named **FLIGHT** and The other is **REGION**

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <strong>Type:</strong>
                {!! Form::select('type', \App\Destination::getEnum('type'),\App\Destination::getEnum('type'), array('onchange' => "admSelectCheck(this);", 'id' => "admOption")) !!}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group" id="admDivCheck" style="display:none;">
                <strong>Flights:</strong>
                {!! Form::text('flights_data', null, array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}
            </div>
        </div>
```

when I select **FLIGHT** the input field **Flights** appears but when I select **REGION** the input field 
 **Flights** still appearing.
I want it to disappear after I select **REGION**.

please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change this one because it always return true:

```
if(admOptionValue === nameSelect.value){
```

to this one:

```
if (admOptionValue === "FLIGHT") {
```

The problem was that `nameSelect.value` is identical to `document.getElementById("admOption").value` because the nameSelect variable actually points to the same element and this is done by calling the javascript function with the `this` reference.

Sample:

```js
function admSelectCheck(nameSelect) {
  if (nameSelect) {
    admOptionValue = document.getElementById("admOption").value;
    if (admOptionValue === "FLIGHT") {
      document.getElementById("admDivCheck").style.display = "block";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("admDivCheck").style.display = "none";
    }
  } else {
    document.getElementById("admDivCheck").style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
  <div class="form-group">
    <strong>Type:</strong>
    <select id="admOption" onchange="admSelectCheck(this);">
      <option>REGION</option>
      <option>FLIGHT</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
  <div class="form-group" id="admDivCheck" style="display:none;">
    <strong>Flights:</strong>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" value="flights data" />
  </div>
</div>
```

In your case, you have to add the flights' condition to the if statement to show the required text field if the `FLIGHTS` option was selected.

Comment: thank you so much, you are what I need :), not the one who votes to me by -1, Thank YOU again, it works well :)